# What does "thought of being bounded" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The record books say that the extent of my domain is 120 acres. But it is obvious that, at every dawn, I am the owner of all the acres I can walk over. It is not only boundaries that disappear, but also the thought of being bounded. Expanses unknown to deed or map are known to every dawn.

(Link to full context: http://www.rvlt.org/newsletter/2002/Fall2002/article5.html)

What does "thought of being bounded" mean?

(1) The thought that I am bounded disappears. I don't think I am bounded at dawn. (Though I think that I am bounded at other time of day.)

(2) At dawn, I don't think about the state of being bounded / the things relating to being bounded. (Maybe from an objective view, like a psychologist thinks about the state of being angry). (Maybe I think about the moon, the wind, or what food is good for health, but not such state.)

Is one of these right? Or it means something else? Thank you!

Comment: I think it means "the thought of losing freedom". Or maybe, *bounded* here means "Being under legal or moral obligation": *bound by my promise.*

Comment: You know, just maybe he's speaking figuratively.  Ya figure?

Comment: Between your suggestions, (1) is more plausible. You can substitute *idea* for *thought* in the quote while retaining its sense.

Answer (score 0):

*Bounded* means delimited by boundaries or constraints.  So you may see in a deed

> the lot **bounded** on the west by Main Street, on the south by Little Creek, ....

The author is saying that every dawn as he walks over the land, he disregards the legal boundaries, making the land open (unbounded), and he figuratively transfers that lack of limitation to himself.

Answer (score 0):

The author seems to be using the concept of legal boundaries, enforced by the record books maintained by the County Clerk, to create contrast between real limitations and government enforced or superficial limitations.

He is reflecting that as he walks over the ground in the morning, before the government official is awake, it is as though the government's books and regulations do not exist and he owns every acre through which he can walk.

The mood or feeling behind the statement, "the thought of being bounded disappears," is one of being naturally powerful and free.

Later in the passage the author says, "He does not claim, but I think he implies, the right to out-blue all bluebirds, and all spiderworts that have turned their faces to the dawn." This statement is in the same vein as the other, as it speaks to a creature's natural right to compete for and lay claim to that which it may organically possess.

Answer (score 0):

The author is saying, in effect, that "every day is a new day, with new opportunities."  He is speaking of figurative bounds, not literal ones, and wakes up each morning feeling as if he knows no boundaries.

In particular, the writer's "domain" includes the animals of the forest, who are most apparent (and seemingly subservient) in the early morning.  After the sun is fully up his "title runs out", as the birds fly off to forage, etc.  And roughly concurrent with that the writer's earthly cares ("the pot is empty") edge out this feeling of freedom.